# sub-URL~how to integrate javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, vs-web-site-project

I found out that integrating code in root-URL and sub-URL is different.

**script route**: `/vendor/assets/custom/js/scripts.js`

Integrating javascript code in this way 
`<script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>` is only working for root-URL and not working for sub-URL.

**root-URL**: `localhost:3000/`

**sub-URL**:   `localhost:3000/homepage/item`

It was solved this way,

`<script src="../../assets/js/scripts.js"></script>`

It's working for both root-URL and sub-URL.

But it's not perfect answer because

if sub-URL length is long, it's not appropriate.

Have to put more `../` to the code so it's not permanent.

Is there the permanent answer to this problem?

This way:

`<script src="ABSOULTE_ADDRESS/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prepend the path just with a slash, for example `<script src="/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>`, then it loads the file relative to the host name part of the URL.